# c# generic abstract class and generic method

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm having some problems with a generic abstract class and it's subclasses, and I don't know how to work it out. I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Loader<T> where T: CommonPoco {
    public virtual List<T> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input, out List<T> result, bool trackProgress) {
        return LoadFromFile(input, out result, trackProgress, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    public abstract List<T> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input, out List<T> result, bool trackProgress, IFormatProvider format);
    public abstract T UploadToDb(List<T> data);
}
```

This is my CommonPoco:

```
public class CommonPoco {
    private int line;
    public int Line {
        get { return line; }
        set { line = value; }
    }

    private string error;
    public string Error {
        get { return error; }
        set { error = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I also have many other subclasses of Loader like this one:

```
public class CountryLoader: Loader<Country> {
    public override List<Country> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input,
        out List<Country> result, bool trackProgress, IFormatProvider format) {
        //Method implementation
    }
    public override Country UploadToDb(List<Country> data) {
        //Method implementation
    }
```

And I also have many subclasses of CommonPoco including the Country class. So far so good. Now to the problem, I would like to implement a, generic?, method. This method will, based on some parameter, use the correct loader for the task. Maybe something like this:

```
void LoadModule<T>(Module module) where T: CommonPoco {
    Loader<T> loader;
    switch (module) {
        case Module.Country:
            loader = new CountryLoader();
            break;
    }
}
```

This does not work and the compiler complains saying it can't convert from CountryLoader to Loader. I have to create a method to load each of my modules and they are exactly the same code except for the initialization of the Loader class. I really hate duplicated code so, how can I achieve this?

Forgot to mention, using .NET Framework 4.0.
I'm willing to change whatever is needed, even my abstract class if I have to. Thanks.
I wonder if using an interface instead of an abstract class would allow me to do this.

Comment: You could use an IoC container such as Castle Windsor, or just reflection.  But why do you have an `out List<T>` parameter in a method with a `List<T>` return value?  That seems very odd.

Comment: `Loader<Country>` (which is `CountryLoader`) is not a `Loader<CommonPoco>`. 

So while `Country` may inherit from `CommonPoco` (even though that relationship isnt mentioned in the above OP), the generic class isnt an inheritance.

Comment: Also, this typically happens when people pass non type specific data (in this case, `module`) and expect strongly typed results. You might need to rethink how you plan on accessing that data if you can't determine the result type.

Comment: constraining `Loader` to `CommonPoco` is not generic. Why not just remove the generic definition and use `CommonPoco` directly in place of `T`.

Comment: @phoog the return value is a list of objects that could not be loaded, so those are the errors. The out param is the actual loaded data.

Comment: @Tejs i agree, my current implementation is wrong and i know why it's wrong, my question is, how can i achieve this i any way :)

Comment: @Jodrell that's a good suggestion, thanks. The main issue still remains though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you turn your abstract class into an Interface, like this:

```
public interface ILoader<T> where T : CommonPoco
    {
        List<T> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input, out List<T> result, bool trackProgress);
        List<T> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input, out List<T> result, bool trackProgress, IFormatProvider format);
        T UploadToDb(List<T> data);
    }
```

Then change your CountryLoader implementation:

```
public class CountryLoader : ILoader<Country>
    {
        public List<Country> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input, out List<Country> result, bool trackProgress)
        {
            return LoadFromFile(input, out result, trackProgress, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        public List<Country> LoadFromFile(StreamReader input,
            out List<Country> result, bool trackProgress, IFormatProvider format)
        {
            //Method implementation
            result = null;
            return null;
        }

        public Country UploadToDb(List<Country> data)
        {
            //Method implementation
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And you create a method like this:

```
void LoadModule<T>(Module module) where T:CommonPoco
        {
            ILoader<T> loader;
            switch (module)
            {
                case Module.Country:
                    loader = new CountryLoader() as ILoader<T>;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The problem with this is that you would have to implement your common LoadFromFile multiple times, unless someone else comes with a way to get around it.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just to clarify, there is no need to turn it into a interface, an abstract class works just fine. The key line is 'loader = new CountryLoader() as Loader<T>;'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason it complains: what if you tried to do it with some other POCO that's not `Country` but pass in country? Example: `LoadModule<Continent>(Module.Country)`? Now what's supposed to happen? It is this ambiguity that will get you into trouble.

The whole point of generic types is that it will work for ANY type that you pass in, but you're trying to set a specific type on a generic variable, regardless of the generic definition, which is bad practice (even when constrained). Keep generics generic. That said, just remove the generic definition and you should be fine.

```
void LoadModule(Module module) {
    Loader<CommonPoco> loader;
    switch (module) {
        case Module.Country:
            loader = (Loader<CommonPoco>)new CountryLoader();
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the premise behind polymorphism, in that you're using interfaces/base classes as the "definition" of what subclasses can/should do. That way, you specify the variable as the parent/base types (in this case, `Loader` and `CommonPoco`), and specific implementations (ie: `CountryLoader`) are just treated as the parent/base type for purposes of functionality (methods and properties).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried this, but it does not work. Still get the same issue.

Comment: It doesn't work because the code SPFiredrake gave is trying to use the type contravariantly. Co/Contravariance only works on interfaces.

Comment: Edited, but I realize this still won't work. Long story short, although a `Country` object is covariant with a `CommonPoco` object, a `Loader<Country>` object is not covariant with `Loader<CommonPoco>`.  In my example, I tried it with an interface, and it still didn't like it (since `Loader` is an abstract class instead of an interface). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

Comment: And yes, changing the `Loader` and `CommonPoco` objects to be interfaces would allow this.

Comment: @SPFiredrake you don't need to change `CommonPoco` to an interface, only `Loader<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an issue with covariant and contravariant types. Depending on which version of C# you're using, you may be able to mark your generic type with the 'in' (covariant) or 'out' (contravariant) markers. E.g., Loader, but in this case, your class is functioning in both a covariant (get safe) and contravariant (set safe) way. You can break up your class definitions to support both use cases, or you can use a more elaborate scheme for type resolution. If you're using an IoC container that supports open-generic resolution of inherited types (Castle Windsor does, StructureMap doesn't) then you can rely on the container to figure out which Loader you want to use in a given case.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, using .net framework 4.0 for this project. And sorry again I have no idea what Castle Windsor or StructureMap are, will google those an check them out.

Comment: Co/contravariance (in/out) can only be used on interfaces, not classes.

Comment: Castle Windsor and StructureMap are Inversion of Control containers. They encapsulate object creation responsibilities (think Factory, Builder and Service Locator patterns). They can inspect a type definition to determine a) how to build it, including dependencies, and b) how to satisfy a request for a given type based on whatever rules are configured.

Comment: Sorry, MgSam, should have made that clear. The above code could be rewritten to use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could try abstracting out the methods in Loader<> into an interface marked as contravariant.

```
public interface ILoader<out T>
```

Then having the Loader base class implement this, and then using a method similar to what SPFiredrake described, except with `ILoader<CommonPoco>`.

Answer (score 0):

but then you could accidentally call something like this

```
villageLoader = LoadModule<Village>(**countryModuleType**) ;
```

and it would be compiler fault that when you expected one loader you get another. see @killinaswine answer why ms developers think it is not a good idea to let you do this.

You can work around this problem on your own risk with type casting.